# what is the code snippet or API for Magnifying glass of webkit on android?

Tags: android

In webkit on android, it has a 'magnifying glass' feature: in the zoom
out view, it has a viewing rectangle which shows the content in 100%.

I wish to use that feature in my application how can i call that mechanism

Will you anyone please Help me out??

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Unfortunately i found the solution to the question which i just asked

as we read in the previous blogs
Magnifying glass feature is not provided as a API
It is in-built feature in the Browser of android that is in webkit
As you all know the Native Apps and third-party Apps are created using the same API's

In the Native App Source code named Browser

Find 1) ToolTip.java 
     2) TextSelector.java
```

ToolTip.java is completely Magnifying glass implementation

TextSelector is used to select the text which can be touched by the user

```
Just make an analyasis of that code and copy the code snippets into your App and mould it to sit in your App
```